# PHP parse error on hello world

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, apache

(warning: beginner) 
So i set up a web server with a apache, mysql, php for OS X tutorial online.

https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Everything is working and i can get on localhost/user/sites/ to open .php scripts. When im doing the simplest things like :

```
<?php
echo "Hi";
?>
```

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"' in
>   /Users/xyz/Sites/test.php on line 11

But there is not even a line 11 to correct something?

I even tried it with html body and so on. not working either.

Apache is working and the mysql server too.
phpMyAdmin is working, i can edit lists on mysql and so on.
phpInfo tells me its version 5.5.38

What can i do to get a simple browser view of what i wrote in my .php doc?

Comment: you are calling it through browser? check your apache error log file

Comment: can you post the exact code you are trying? are you editing the right file?

Comment: where can i see my error log files? in terminal?

Comment: have you installed `PHP` on your server?

Comment: it is the code i wrote above. 3 lines, copy pasted them. nothing more

Comment: What do you mean php installed on server, i mean it tells me i got it and got the version 5.5.38 so i guess, just followed the tutorial

Comment: for running `php` files you should have install php on server.

Comment: or use something like https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_osx.html

Comment: do you have trailing spaces (new lines) after the php closing tag?

Comment: how can i do that? command in terminal or downloading something online or what?

Comment: no spaces, just whats standing there.

Comment: sorry its for my workstation, have to get this done not with xampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if **short_open_tags** are enabled, then you can't begin your PHP scripts with an XML declaration.
PHP will see the `<?` and reclaim it for itself. It won't understand what the stray `php` was meant for. It'll get interpreted as constant. But the `echo` will be seen as another literal/constant. And since the parser can't make sense of two subsequent literals/values without an expression operator in between, that'll be a parser failure.

**EDIT :** (solution approved by OP)

it's **Invisible Unicode characters** issue. Changing code editor solved the problem

Comment: try disabling **short_open_tags** in your php.ini

Comment: sometimes this error is caused by **Invisible Unicode characters**. if it's the case, you can look for more information about the possible workarounds but i recommand changing your editor

Comment: wow... thanks taha, you saved my life. My boss told me to just use text editor that preinstalled program on mac. I got to textmate now, wrote same thing, saved .php and worked. Thanks so much !

Comment: Glad I helped :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Make a folder in your htdocs. 
After that make in your new folder a file that named "index.php"and put your code in this file.
Than go to your browser and put this link: "localhost/youfoldername"

Is see your link */Users/xyz/Sites/test.php*. You have to work in your htdocs folder

To find you the htdocs folder: Open your xampp surface and than click on "Open application folder"

Comment: He is working on `OS X` i.e. `MAC OS` not on `Windows`

Comment: Same principle with OS X

Comment: Before edit: you mentioned `C:/` that's why it was wrong and he is beginner he might get confused.
After Edit: He may try this.

Comment: sorry where can i find htdocs folder? don't see any on my mac

Comment: im a beginner in php and mysql and yea i switched from windows to mac cause of my workstation at the company, i know what the difference from c:/ is